# why svcutil.exe ignoring targetnamespace in xsd

Tags: c#, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

can somebody explain me why svcutil.exe is ignoring targetnamespace when it is generating c# code from wsdl and xsd?

if I use: `svcutil.exe /importXmltypes /useSerializerForFaults /noLogo  /language:cs  serializer:XmlSerializer /async MyService.wsdl MyService_sc*.xsd`

it generates code but some classes are not in namespace under which they was in xsd

but if I use: `svcutil.exe /dconly /importXmltypes /useSerializerForFaults /noLogo  /language:cs /serializer:XmlSerializer MyService_sc*.xsd`

then it generates code and everything is under some namespace (not global)

I would like to use first command and has everything under correct namespace....
Thanks

Comment: Did you try the [/namespace:<string,string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) switch?

Comment: yeah, I can use it /namespace:*,N but then is everything in N and I want to have it in their own namespace... and even if I use /namespace for all namespaces, it is not working for everything...